# Modification de « rien » au passé composé

Tags: négation, ordre-des-mots, passé-composé

Je sais quand on utilise « rien » au passé, il se place entre le verbe auxiliaire et le participe passé (e.g. je n'ai rien vu), mais comment ça s'écrit quand on ajoute une locution prépositive pour modifier « rien » ? Par exemple :

> Je n'ai vu rien d'important.

ou

> Je n'ai rien vu d'important.

Y aurait-il un troisième choix qui me manque ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I**

Pour « (dire, bien) » et « (faire, bien) » [ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rien+dit+de+bien%2Cdit+rien+de+bien&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crien%20dit%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdit%20rien%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crien%20dit%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdit%20rien%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0), [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fait+rien+de+bien%2Crien+fait+de+bien&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfait%20rien%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crien%20fait%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0) il n'existe pas de différence dans la fréquence d'utilisation des deux possibilités. Des données ne sont pas disponibles pour « (voir, important) » mais on ne peut pas appliquer des règles au cas par cas, ce qui signifie que les deux possibilités sont acceptables ; cependant, la seconde semble préférable ; on pourrait croire cela à partir de ce [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rien+appris+de+bien%2Cappris+rien+de+bien&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crien%20appris%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappris%20rien%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crien%20appris%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappris%20rien%20de%20bien%3B%2Cc0) pour « (apprendre, bien) ». Cela semble confirmé pour « [(dire, précis)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+dit+rien+de+pr%C3%A9cis%2C*+rien+dit+de+pr%C3%A9cis&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20dit%20rien%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bne%20dit%20rien%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnous%20dit%20rien%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A%20rien%20dit%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bn%27ont%20rien%20dit%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bn%27a%20rien%20dit%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20dit%20rien%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bne%20dit%20rien%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnous%20dit%20rien%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C*%20rien%20dit%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bn'ont%20rien%20dit%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bn'a%20rien%20dit%20de%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0) ».

Lorsque l'on modifie l'adjectif au moyen d'un adverbe il semble que tout au moins pour certaines combinaisons, la situation soit renversée ([(dire, bien précis)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dit+rien+de+bien+pr%C3%A9cis%2Crien+dit+de+bien+pr%C3%A9cis&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdit%20rien%20de%20bien%20pr%C3%A9cis%3B%2Cc0)).

**II**

Il existe le cas du placement de la locution en tête de phrase pour donner plus de force à l'assertion, mais c'est tout. Dans ce cas il ne faut pas intervertir « voir » et « rien ».

- D'important, je n'ai rien vu.

Answer (score 5):

La forme idiomatique est :

> ***Je n'ai rien vu d'important.***

Google Books en trouve [une dizaine depuis 1900](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22je%20n%27ai%20rien%20vu%20d%27important%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:2020&tbm=bks&ei=jnqxXMDaCLGtgweUkKiABw&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjA2a3isczhAhWx1uAKHRQICnA4ChDy0wMILA&biw=1427&bih=741&dpr=1), et un peu plus dans les pages web.

En revanche, il ne trouve que [deux occurrences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22je%20n%27ai%20vu%20rien%20d%27important%22&filter=0&biw=1427&bih=741) pour

> Je n'ai vu rien d'important

Ce sont d'une part ta question et d'autre part une page de cours de français en italien, probablement influencée par l'italien *Non ho visto niente di importante*.

Sans que les formes avec *rien* placé après le participe passé ne soient grammaticalement incorrectes, on ne peut que constater leur grande rareté.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Plus généralement en ce qui a trait au pronom indéfini [*rien*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rien) :

> [...] Lorsque *rien* remplit une fonction de complément d’objet direct,
>   on le place après le verbe d’un temps simple. **Quand il est utilisé
>   avec un verbe d’un temps composé, il s’insère généralement entre
>   l’auxiliaire et le participe passé; toutefois, *rien* sera le plus
>   souvent placé après le temps composé s’il est suivi d’un complément.**
>   Finalement, lorsque *rien* est complément d’un infinitif, il est placé
>   avant le verbe. Dans ce dernier cas, rien peut être suivi ou précédé
>   du pronom adverbial y.
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique (OQLF), « [rien](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3886) », je souligne ]

---

> ***Rien*** objet direct se place devant un infinitif, et entre l'auxiliaire et le participe passé dans les temps composés [...]
>
> Si *rien* a un complément, il est plus courant que cet ensemble suive
>   l'infinitif et le participe (*Leur séparation n'avait eu rien de
>   pénible*. Flaubert). [...]
>
> Cependant, même dans ce cas [...], on trouve souvent *rien* séparé de
>   son complément et placé avant l'infinitif et le participe [...] (*Je
>   n'ai rien trouvé de coupable en cet homme.* Bible, trad. Crampon)
>   [...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup> §
>   300 d), aussi 684 a) ; fragments du texte ]

Je ne crois pas que « d'important » soit une [locution prépositive](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Locutions_pr%C3%A9positives_en_fran%C3%A7ais), il s'agit d'un complément.